I am encountering an error when trying to connect to dbt-redshift through AWS CLI from my terminal. Here are the details:
Encountered an error loading local configuration: dbt_cloud.yml credentials file for dbt Cloud not found. Download your credentials file from dbt Cloud to C:\Users\LENOVO\.dbt
Note:
- Am using a paid service of redshift, so i have to use it from my machine using aws CLI
Steps Taken:
- Installed AWS CLI and configured it using aws configure.
- Installed dbt and created the necessary profiles in profiles.yml.
- Attempted to run dbt debug to test the connection.
- Verified the credentials and configurations in profiles.yml.
- Checked the file paths and ensured that profiles.yml is in the correct location.
- Updated dbt to the latest version.
